# Interactive function with two functions

Tags: interactive

Would like to have an interactive function that enables or disables two features (either `auto-complete` or `company`).  Is this how I can use the interactive clause to pass two function arguments?  I get confused because customarily, let returns only one thing, the result of the last command.

```
(defun complt (featr actm)
  "Enable or disable text completion."

  (interactive
   (list
    (let* ( (cseq '("acomplt" "company"))
            (cftr (completing-read "Featr: " cseq nil t "company"))
            (csel (completing-read "Actm: " 
                     '("disable" "enable") nil t "enable")) )
    cftr 
    csel))) 

  (message "DO THIS") 
  (message "DO THAT"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `let` returns a single value, while for passing two values via 'interactive' you would like to pass a list containing two elements/values,

therefore, just place the `list` inside the let as follows to get what you want:

```lisp
(defun complt (featr actm)
  "Enable or disable text completion."

  (interactive
    (let* ( (cseq '("acomplt" "company"))
            (cftr (completing-read "Featr: " cseq nil t "company"))
            (csel (completing-read "Actm: "
                                   '("disable" "enable") nil t "enable")) )
      (list cftr csel)))

  (message "DO THIS")
  (message "DO THAT"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have confused these two things: `(list (form a b))` and `(form (list a b))`.

I think a simpler way to write this avoids `let` entirely:

```
(defun complt (featr actm)
  "Enable or disable text completion."

  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Featr: " '("acomplt" "company") nil t "company")
    (completing-read "Actm: " '("disable" "enable") nil t "enable")))

  (message "DO THIS")
  (message "DO THAT"))
```

Here is another version using `let`:

```
(defun complt (featr actm)
  "Enable or disable text completion."

  (interactive
   (list
    (let ((choices '("acomplt" "company"))
          (completing-read "Featr: " choices nil t "company")))
    (let ((choices '("disable" "enable"))
          (completing-read "Actm: " choices nil t "enable")))))

  (message "DO THIS")
  (message "DO THAT"))
```